# How to create a list of R markdown files in R?

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements, r-markdown

I want to create two lists of R markdown files from my current working directory. I am starting with two empty lists, that I want to populate with these RMDs using a specific strategy. In my current working directory, I have the following hierarchy:

```
CWD
{ FOLDER #1
--> Q1.Rmd, Q2.Rmd, Q3.Rmd

FOLDER #2
--> Q4.Rmd, Q5.Rmd, Q6.Rmd, Q7.Rmd

FOLDER #3
--> Q8.Rmd, Q9.Rmd, Q10.Rmd, Q11.Rmd

FOLDER #SPECIAL_1
--> Qa.Rmd, Qb.Rmd, Qc.Rmd

FOLDER #SPECIAL_2
--> Qx.Rmd, Qy.Rmd, Qz.Rmd
}
```

What I would like the code to do would be: Go through each non-special folder (Folder #1, Folder #2, Folder #3), take half of the questions and put them in the list_1, and half in the list_2 (if the number of questions is not divisible by 2 take a random number of questions to the list_1 and a random number to the list_2), and then attach at the end all the questions in the special folder, one after the other in the order they appear in the special folders, for the corresponding list (i.e., for the list_1 put at the end Qa.Rmd, Qb.Rmd, Qc.Rmd and for the list_2 Qx, Qy and Qz.

A possible output of the code could be:

```
list_1 would contain:

- Q1.Rmd, Q2.Rmd, Q4.Rmd, Q5.Rmd, Q9.Rmd, Q10.Rmd,Qa.Rmd, Qb.Rmd, Qc.Rmd.
```

```
list_2 would contain:

- Q3.Rmd, Q6.Rmd, Q7.Rmd, Q8.Rmd, Q11.Rmd, Qx.Rmd, Qy.Rmd, Qz.Rmd
```

It is important that there are no duplicates from the list_1 to list_2.

Would there be any way to achieve this in R code?